# Javascript function not working after switching to whirlpool

Tags: javascript, php

I've been following a guide to make a secure login page ( given I'm a newbie to PHP, and I'm trying to learn it ); they use javascript as a processor after you've clicked "submit" on the register page, and the login page. However, the function seems to be broken. I've edited it, so that the salt is converted to whirlpool, instead of sha512.
Here's the function ( also, the link to the guide: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL )

Function:

```
function formhash(form, password) {
    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = whirlpool(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit();
}

function regformhash(form, uid, email, password, conf) {
     // Check each field has a value
    if (uid.value == ''         || 
          email.value == ''     || 
          password.value == ''  || 
          conf.value == '') {

        alert('You must provide all the requested details. Please try again');
        return false;
    }

    // Check the username

    re = /^\w+$/; 
    if(!re.test(form.username.value)) { 
        alert("Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores. Please try again"); 
        form.username.focus();
        return false; 
    }

    // Check that the password is sufficiently long (min 6 chars)
    // The check is duplicated below, but this is included to give more
    // specific guidance to the user
    if (password.value.length < 6) {
        alert('Passwords must be at least 6 characters long.  Please try again');
        form.password.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // At least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter 
    // At least six characters 

    var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/; 
    if (!re.test(password.value)) {
        alert('Passwords must contain at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter.  Please try again');
        return false;
    }

    // Check password and confirmation are the same
    if (password.value != conf.value) {
        alert('Your password and confirmation do not match. Please try again');
        form.password.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = whirlpool(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";
    conf.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem, are you getting errors? What is in your console?

Comment: I'm not getting any returns. When I try to click the button, it's not working. And the code for the button is correct, because I tested it with a simple pop up.